# Mapping sampleRegions() over an ImageCollection (GEE)

Tags: gis, google-earth-engine

I am a relatively new user of GEE. I am having issues when trying to map() the function sampleRegions() over an image collection (S2 2A product). The result I would like to obtain is to add to each feature (points) of my initial feature collection the corresponding band values of every image in the collection.
However, when I try to map the function over an image collection, I get an empty output. I tried different sort of casting but to me the issues does not seem to be there. Anyone has any idea of why and how can I solve? See code below for an example

```
// Load S2 for the time period of interest       
var s2_ts = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2_SR") // Level-2A Surface reflectance
                    .filterDate("2021-05-12" , "2021-06-05")
                    .filter(ee.Filter.eq('MGRS_TILE', '32TPN')
                    .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 20))

// Select the bands of interest 
var s2_ts = s2_ts.map(function(image){
  return image.select('B2','B3','B4','B5')
})
print(s2_ts)

// Just a random example of a feature (point) collection
var myFeatures = ee.FeatureCollection('WRI/GPPD/power_plants')
                                     .filter(ee.Filter.eq('country', 'ITA'));
                                     
print(myFeatures, 'My Features')

// Map sampleRegions() over the S2 image collection
var fullDataset = ee.FeatureCollection(s2_ts.map(function(image){
  return image.sampleRegions({
    collection: myFeatures, 
    scale: 10, 
    geometries: true}).flatten();
}));

print(fullDataset,'Full dataset with S2 bands in properties') // Empty result...
```

I was expecting the map function to give an output like a collection of feature collections.